# How to make osm2pgsql import a tag?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

I loaded OSM data into PostgeSQL with Osmosis&Osm2PgSQL, and see many tags are missing. I need to make it import `lanes` tag. How can I make it save this tag too?

**edit:** my solution was to copy /usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style into a new file, edit it adding a line:

```
way   lanes         int4         linear
```

then call osm2pgsql with parameter:

```
osm2pgsql ... --style my.style
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With osm2pgsql, you have to edit the `default.style` file.

it is a simple text file, so any text editor will do.

For including lanes, add a line

```
node,way   lane     text         linear
```

you have to re-import your data afterwards.

If you have installed the hstore, you could extract the tags from there, but that's a bit more difficult.

Comment: yep, found it too. I used int4 as data type